# Only one event is triggred even i pass more that one event

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have passed 4 event in a bloc like

```
`BlocProvider<HomeBloc>(
    create: (context) => homeBloc
      ..add(const HomeEvent.getStories())
      ..add(const HomeEvent.getBestWorking())
      ..add(const HomeEvent.getTrending())
      ..add(
        const HomeEvent.getDancing(),
      ),
child:widget)`
```

Also here is my bloc :

```
`on<HomeEvent>((event, emit) {
  event.when(
    getStories: () async {
      emit(HomeState.onStoriesSuccess(storiesList));
      return;
    },
    getTrending: () => emit(HomeState.onTrendingSuccess(trendingList)),
    getBestWorking: () =>
        emit(HomeState.onBestWorkingSuccess(bestWorkingList)),
    getDancing: () => emit(HomeState.onDancingSuccess(dancingList)),
  );
 });`
```

but i am getting only last one event i.e HomeEvent.getDancing().I am trying to get all response from all of those events.

I am trying to get all event so that i can render all at once in UI

Answer (score 0):

Each `Bloc` can only have one state at a time. If you call `emit()` you change that state to the value provided in the method. Therefore, you only get the state from the last `emit()` call.

A solution could be to have multiple boolean properties in the event which specify what to load and a state with properties which contain the loaded data or are empty if the corresponding boolean property of the event was false.